# How to Add XY Values to each Cross Profile record when using SAGA Cross Profile Algorithm

Tags: qgis, saga

When using the SAGA algorithm to create Cross profiles of depths from a DEM is there any way to add XY values to **each** of the depth values created and stored in the attribute table?

Answer (score 0):

Two tools in `Processing Toolbox - Vector geometry` will be useful:

(1) Use **Extract vertices** tool on your `Cross Profiles` line layer. This will create a point layer (usually named "Vertices") with all relevant information per each vertex. You will find new attribute **vertex_index**. Since the vertex_number starts from zero, please add one (1) to find the matching **Pxx** number produced by the SAGA Cross Profile algorithm.

(2) Then use **Add geometry attributes** tool to add X, Y, and the depth values (namely `xcoord`, `ycoord`, and `zcoord`).

[image]